# Connecting actions to store outside a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

So let's suppose I have a store, with a `redux-thunk` middleware in it. I created the store and exported it like this:

```
import myOwnCreateStoreMethod from './redux/createStore';
export const store = myOwnCreateStoreMethod();
```

I can now access it anywhere in my app. But what if I want to dispatch an action from anywhere? I have them declared e.g. in `myAction.js`:

```
export const myAction = () => (dispatch, getState) =>
    dispatch({ type: 'SOME_TYPE', payload: ... })
```

Now I can import them and connect to my store/component like this:

```
import * as actions from './myActions.js';

const MyComponent = () => <div>Hello World</div>;
const mapStateToProps = () => ({});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(MyComponent);
```

My question is - what if I do not have a component and still want to dispatch actions declared like the one above?

Comment: your store is public and unique... you can "import store from ..." in your module, and call store.dispatch(myAction()) in any method, without a component

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can dispatch actions from the `store` directly

```
import store from './myStore';
import { myAction } from './myAction';    

store.dispatch(myAction());
```

Redux is a library by itself.

It has nothing to do with React, they just work well together based on React single source of truth and Redux one global store as the state of our application.

You can use redux in every JavaScript application.

Comment: exactly, like this call

Comment: Ah, this is so easy. I did not know why I was overcomplicating this :/ I'll answer my question with a solution, but accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, so easy after @Asaf Aviv wrote his simple answer. So I implemented it like this:

```
import * as yourActions from './redux/actions/yourActions';
import { store } from './path/to/your/store';

const connectActions = (store, actions) => {
  const { dispatch } = store;
  return Object.keys(actions).reduce((acc, key) => {
    const action = props => dispatch(actions[key](props));
    acc[key] = action;
    return acc;
  }, {});
};

const connectedActions = connectActions(store, yourActions);
```